# How do I make a dictionary that doesn't return brackets

Tags: python, csv, dictionary

I'm trying to make a dictionary that uses the call function 'findPokemonInfo(name)' and iterates through my csv file and returns information in this format:

attack: 49

capture_rate: 45

name: Bulbasaur

speed: 45

type: grass

The csv file is displayed like this: name,type,attack,speed,capture_rate

This is what I currently have:

```py
def findPokemonInfo(name): 
    import csv 
    myFile = open('pokemon.csv',"r")
    csvReader = csv.reader(myFile,delimiter=",")
    next(csvReader)
    pokeMon = {}
    for row in csvReader:
        if (row[0] == name):
            pokeMon[row[0]] = {'attack':row[2], 'capture_rate':row[4], 'name':row[0], 'speed':row[3], 'type':row[1]}
            print (pokeMon)
```

Which returns:

findPokemonInfo('Bulbasaur')

```
{'Bulbasaur': {'attack': '49', 'capture_rate': '45', 'name': 'Bulbasaur', 'speed': '45', 'type': 'grass'}}
```

Comment: import your library (import csv) at the top of your file, not inside a function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Print your dictionary this way:

```
d = {'Bulbasaur': {'attack': '49', 'capture_rate': '45', 'name': 'Bulbasaur', 'speed': '45', 'type': 'grass'}}

for key in d:
    for sub_key in d[key]:
        print(sub_key,": ", d[key][sub_key])
```

The output will be this:

```
attack :  49
capture_rate :  45
name :  Bulbasaur
speed :  45
type :  grass
```

Comment: This function would only create a dictionary with 'Bulbasaur', that was just an example i was using. Is there anyway I could use this convert this code for different variables(different 'names')

Comment: @Jacob Just replace `d` with whatever variable you want to use. If it's a list of dicts, iterate the list first.